# LINQ to Object basic codes

Tags: c#, linq

I'm thinking a list of lists like this.

```
    var myList = new List<List<string>>();
    myList.Add(new List<string> { "#16", "100%", "Monitor" });
    myList.Add(new List<string> { "#19", "98%", "Guide" });
    myList.Add(new List<string> { "#77", "0%", "Cord" });
```

From codes like this.

```
    string mySource = @"
    #16
    100%
    Monitor
    #19
    98%
    Guide
    #77
    0%
    Cord
    ";
    var myPattern = @"#(\d+)\r\n(\d+)%\r\n([^\r\n]*)\r\n";
    var myCollection = Regex.Matches(mySource, myPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => Regex.Split(x.Value, "\r\n"))
    .ToList();
```

Obviously in the middle of the "Matches" it has an array.

How can I change it into a list of lists ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously in the middle of the "Matches" it has an array.

Obviously you have to convert it into a list.

```
//.Select(x => Regex.Split(x.Value, "\r\n"))
.Select(x => Regex.Split(x.Value, "\r\n").ToList())
```

---

```
var pattern = string.Join(@"\r\n", @"(?<id>#\d+)", @"(?<percent>\d+%)", @"(?<name>\w+)");
Regex.Matches(mySource, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => new[] //or you can use : m => new List<string>
    {
        m.Groups["id"].Value,
        m.Groups["percent"].Value,
        m.Groups["name"].Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing. If I'd like to a list of arrys. I think, I do not need "Split". Am I right (it is just a wild guess.).

Comment: I mean, is there any way to use "Group submatches" or something ? (Split is make an array again. It is double processing, I guess..)

Comment: For your first question, you will still have to split them as each match contains a string with 3lines. For your second question, it is perfectly possible. Gimme a minute to update it.

Comment: For instance,    .Select(x => someArry[x.Groups[1].Value], x => someArry[x.Groups[2].Value])) (I konw it's not working)...

Comment: You will also need to modify your regex, if you were using that method. Since the `#` is not included in the first group, nor the `%` from the second. I don't know if that is intended. Or... you could just use mine.

Comment: Never mind (RegEx) details. I (You) can handle it with easy. Your codes looks great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ToList` extension method an `Array` to convert to `List`

```
string mySource = @"
#16
100%
Monitor
#19
98%
Guide
#77
0%
Cord
";
var myPattern = @"#(\d+)\r\n(\d+)%\r\n([^\r\n]*)\r\n";
var myCollection = Regex.Matches(mySource, myPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(x => Regex.Split(x.Value, "\r\n").ToList())
.ToList();
```

Comment: I'm modifying codes a bit. I'm trying a list of arry. And (thinking) using the submatches already made. Regards